# Add all Ant tasks and types within a .jar to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

Is there a way to add all Ant tasks and types within `.jar` to Eclipse? I'm using a `build.xml` file and I would like Eclipse to recognize the additional tasks in a `.jar` if only to offer task name completion. There is a way within the preferences to add `.jar` files to the Ant class path, and there is a way to add each task/type manually to Eclipse, but there does not seem any automated way of adding tasks.

And as I am adding about 3 .jar files with about 20 tasks each for a special runtime, it's going to be very error prone and painstaking work to add them all without typos. The tasks all extend `Task` in Ant, if that is any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the taskdef task documented in http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html.

Aside from using it to define an individual task, you can use it to define a group of tasks.

> You can also define a group of definitions at once using the file or resource attributes. These attributes point to files in the format of Java property files or an xml format.

Example:

```
<taskdef resource="thirdparty/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="./jar">
            <include name="**/customTasksJar.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

(assuming that the Jar is placed in a folder named jar in the directory where the buildfile exists)

The antlib.xml should exist in the Jar file (in this case in a folder thirdparty) and should define the tasks of this Jar. Or even better you can place a properties file instead of an xml that contains the task definitions (one in each line) in the below format:

```
typename1=fully.qualified.java.classname1
typename2=fully.qualified.java.classname2
...
```

If the Jar containing the tasks is correctly placed as specified in the `fileset` above, you should be able to have auto task completion in Eclipse.

Comment: After fixing some interesting classpath issues **in the `build.xml`** I was able to have completion for my own build tasks, thanks (this should almost double your current rep, congrats).